# Where should I put my named pipes on RHEL7?

Tags: rhel7, named-pipes

I done some quicky web searches to find out how to make a named pipe. It looks very straight forward I just need to execute as root: mkfifo filename, but what the best practice on where on the filesystem to put named pipes? Should they go into /tmp, /var/tmp, /var/lib or somewhere else? Also should I follow any naming convention or is there names I should avoid?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no "standard" per se, but it ultimately depends on what you are doing.  If you are writing an application that will use a named pipe as an interface, they tend to go into /var/run/.

The good news is that it's really entirely up to you - it mostly depends on who should have access to it and who shouldn't. It's important to make sure it's in a directory that will help enforce the proper permissions to your application/script that you are running.

Comment: Yep I am writing a custom syslog parser application. Thanks!